# Generators in group theory

Tags: group-theory, rotation, matrix-elements

When we consider rotation matrix along $z$ axis and take the infinitesimal value the parameter (rotation angle), we get corresponding generator of the rotation.It has the form shown in the equation.
$$J_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &-i & 0 \\
i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now we say by taking exponential I.e. $e^{iJ_{3}\alpha}$ we obtain rotation matrix corresponding to rotation angle $\alpha$.
But my question is how can we take exponential of $J_3$? Because it is a singular matrix, 3rd column and 3rd row elements are zero.This matrix can't be diagonalizable. In the sense that if we use the expression $P D P^{-1}$. To determine $P^{-1}$ , we need the matrix  $J_3$ to be diagonalizable.

Comment: This matrix is Hermitian so is certainly diagonalisable.

Comment: Yes, singular matrices can be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness (although the other answers are probably simpler) the matrix $J_3$ can be written as:

$$ J_3 = \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}& 0 \\i/\sqrt{2} & -i \sqrt{2}& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} & -i/\sqrt{2}& 0 \\1/\sqrt{2} & i \sqrt{2}& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

and its matrix exponential can be computed by exponentiating the diagonal matrix to give:

$$ \exp(\alpha J_3) = \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}& 0 \\i/\sqrt{2} & -i \sqrt{2}& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}e^\alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-\alpha} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} & -i/\sqrt{2}& 0 \\1/\sqrt{2} & i \sqrt{2}& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\exp(\alpha J_3) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & \sin\alpha & 0 \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that invertibility has nothing to do with diagonalisability. In particular, matrices with determinant zero can usually be diagonalised.

Answer (score 6):

You really don't need to overthink it. Just do it.

Note that
$$
J_3^2= \operatorname {diag} ( 1,1,0) \equiv K; ~~~~J_3^3=J_3.
$$
You then expand the exponential of the matrix, as normally [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential),
$$
\exp ( i\alpha J_3) = I + i\alpha J_3 + ( i\alpha J_3 )^2 /2!+ ( i\alpha J_3 )^3/3! +...\\
= \operatorname{diag} ( 0,0,1) + \cos\alpha ~K + i\sin\alpha ~J_3\\
=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha & 0 \\
-\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now explore what various values for *α*  signify on the *x-y* plane: *π/4, π/2, π, 2π*. It is a bland rotation. The *z* direction is left alone.

Answer (score 5):

The exponential of a matrix is defined through its power series:
\begin{equation}
e^A = \sum_{n= 0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}
\end{equation}

Comment: The matrix *is* diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $+1,0,-1$.

Comment: How? Its determinent is zero.

Comment: @prakeshkumardora The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. It’s zero because *one* of the eigenvalues is zero, not because all are.

Comment: @prakeshkumardora There is no connection between diagonalizability and invertibility. Note that $J_3$ is an element of the Lie *algebra*, not the Lie group and is not required to have an inverse.